# StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle not found in AppKernel

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I'm using Symfony2 v2.1.9 and I'm facing a problem while installing  `StofDoctrineExtensionBundle`

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle' not found in C:/wamp/www/Symfony/app/AppKernel.php on line 23 .
```

AppKernel.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;



class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
            new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
            new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),


            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
             new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),

        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();

        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

autoload.php

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// intl
if (!function_exists('intl_get_error_code')) {
    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php';

    $loader->add('', __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs');

}


AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

After installing that what i get at console

Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
      - Updating twig/extensions dev-master (5c2d515 => v1.0.0)
        Checking out v1.0.0

vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php

```
<?php

// autoload_namespaces.php generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'WhiteOctober\\PagerfantaBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/white-october/pagerfanta-bundle'),
    'Twig_Extensions_' => array($vendorDir . '/twig/extensions/lib'),
    'Twig_' => array($vendorDir . '/twig/twig/lib'),
    'Symfony\\Bundle\\SwiftmailerBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle'),
    'Symfony\\Bundle\\MonologBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/monolog-bundle'),
    'Symfony\\Bundle\\AsseticBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/assetic-bundle'),
    'Symfony' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/symfony/src'),
    'SessionHandlerInterface' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Resources/stubs'),
    'Sensio\\Bundle\\GeneratorBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/sensio/generator-bundle'),
    'Sensio\\Bundle\\FrameworkExtraBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/sensio/framework-extra-bundle'),
    'Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/sensio/distribution-bundle'),
    'Pagerfanta\\' => array($vendorDir . '/pagerfanta/pagerfanta/src'),
    'Monolog' => array($vendorDir . '/monolog/monolog/src'),
    'Metadata\\' => array($vendorDir . '/jms/metadata/src'),
    'JMS\\SecurityExtraBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/jms/security-extra-bundle'),
    'JMS\\DiExtraBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/jms/di-extra-bundle'),
    'JMS\\AopBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/jms/aop-bundle'),
    'FOS\\UserBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle'),
    'Doctrine\\ORM' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/orm/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\DBAL' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/dbal/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/common/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Bundle\\DoctrineBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/doctrine-bundle'),
    'CG\\' => array($vendorDir . '/jms/cg/src'),
    'Assetic' => array($vendorDir . '/kriswallsmith/assetic/src'),
    '' => array($baseDir . '/src'),
);
```

Comment: Have you carefully checked the [installation guide](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst#installation) in the documentation?

Comment: yes sure,although i have the same errors

Comment: The `Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle` namespace is not registered. Please post your composer.json too.

Answer (score 2):

```
error: Class 'xxxBundle' not found in .../app/AppKernel.php
```

means usually the bundle is not installed yet. For unexperienced users the installation guide is missing one important point. After adding a requirement to the `composer.json` you have to run the update command:

```
php composer.phar update
```

Comment: In fact that what i had did .i had run the update commande. the installation succeeded so i found stof and gedmo  directories in vendor

Comment: hmpf, dammit ^^ Can you edit the contents of the `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php` file into your question?

Comment: I tried to install the bundle  manually but That does still not work